# 'SFDX: Retrieve Source in Mainfest from Org' not retrieving the components

Tags: vs-code

In VS Code, I performed these steps:

1. Ran the command 'SFDX: Create Project with Manifest'.
2. Ran the command 'SFDX: Authorize an Org' and authorized the org.
3. Right-clicked the package.xml file and clicked ' SFDX: Retrieve Source in Manifest from Org'.

After the process of retrieving the components ran, I then expanded the force-app menu, but I cannot see any of the components underneath. For instance, when I expand the 'classes' menu under 'force-app', I cannot see any of the Apex classes in my org. I am not sure why this isn't working.

After step 3 was completed, the output displayed this-

sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest c:\Users\The PATH\manifest\package.xml
ERROR:  Error: read ECONNRESET
Unhandled rejection Error: read ECONNRESET
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest c:\Users\THE PATH\manifest\package.xml
ended with exit code 0

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that a network issue occurred and your connection was reset whilst retrieving the package.

I get this error ever so often, re-trying usually helps.